# How to get thumbnail image of video from ALAsset in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, alassetslibrary, cmtime

I want to get thumbnail images of every frame from video and then save this images in Mutable Array of images.

I want to use this images to play as a animation.

```
NSURL* assetURL = [self.asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyAssetURL];
NSDictionary* assetOptions = nil;

AVAsset* myAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:assetURL options:assetOptions];

self.imageGenerator = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:myAsset];


int duration = CMTimeGetSeconds([myAsset duration]);

for(int i = 0; i<duration; i++)
{
    CGImageRef imgRef = [self.imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:CMTimeMake(i, duration) actualTime:NULL error:nil];
    UIImage* thumbnail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef scale:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    [thumbnailImages addObject:thumbnail];
}
```

I am using above code to get thumbnail images but the problem is if there is a 2 seconds video i am only getting 2 thumbnails but i want 20 thumbnails (10 thumbnail per second).

So, how to use CMTimeMake to get thumbnails for every .1 second

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code form reference site : [**Thumbnail image from Video**](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/05/thumbnail-image-of-video-from.html)

**Objective - C**

```
-(UIImage *)generateThumbImage : (NSString *)filepath
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];

    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
self.imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES; 
        CMTime time = [asset duration];
        time.value = 0;
        Float duration = CMTimeGetSeconds([myAsset duration]);
   for(Float i = 0.0; i<duration; i=i+0.1)
    {
     CGImageRef imgRef = [self.imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:CMTimeMake(i, duration) actualTime:NULL error:nil];
     UIImage* thumbnail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef scale:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    [thumbnailImages addObject:thumbnail];
    }
}
```

**Swift**

```
func generateThumbImage(url : NSURL) -> UIImage{
        var asset : AVAsset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(url) as! AVAsset
        var assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        var error       : NSError? = nil
        var time        : CMTime = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
        var img         : CGImageRef = assetImgGenerate.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil, error: &error)
        var frameImg    : UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: img)!

        return frameImg
    }
```

Comment: Hey, your code returns only one image. I want array of all thumbnail images. Thanks

Comment: Then its not Called Thumb image.

Comment: like you generated one image at any given time, i want multiple images from diff. time and show as animation

Comment: hey  i updated my question according to your code, but there is a little logical problem. Can you help me?

Comment: @lalit Kumar , Change your for loop for(float i = 0.0,i<duration; i=i+0.1) may be get all thumbs.

Comment: Thanks. can you help me on this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/31333375/3976183

Answer (score 1):

@Kirit Modi solution in Swift 3 with some small changes:

```
func generateThumbImage(url : URL) -> UIImage?{

  let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
  let assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
  let time = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
  let img = try? assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)

  guard let cgImage = img else { return nil }

  let frameImg    = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
  return frameImg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code for the getting the thumb image from video at `0.41`

```
NSString *str = [[self.videoArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"vName"];
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:str] ;
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL]autorelease];
UIImage  *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:0.41 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
player = nil;
```

Comment: I want all thumbnail images from asset (which is type of video), not single image.

Comment: you need to change the value of the `thumbnailImageAtTime:0.41`

Comment: I am trying your code also. But i am using ALAsset. So, may you edit your answer in respect to ALAsset

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UIImageView{
func getImageThumnail(forLink link: String) {
    let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(string: link)!)
    let assetImgGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(50), 100)
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
      do {
            let img = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
            let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: img)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = thumbnail
            }
    } catch {
    }
    }
}
}
```